# ruby giving output without print statement

Tags: ruby

This piece of code in ruby is giving output eventhough I am not using print/puts.Please help me figure out why

```
def display_something
    p yield
end

display_something {"say something"}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `display_someting`, you are using a print method (`p`) on the yield. This means that when you pass "say something" to the display_something method, it is printing your string.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `p` which is equivalent to calling `puts X.inspect` - you are yielding to a block containing a string, basically calling `puts "say something".inspect`